# Add icons to Glass Launcher

Tags: launcher, google-glass

Is it possible to add app shortcuts to the Glass Launcher on the Google Glass (Glass Enterprise Edition 2 in my case)? If so, how?

To be clear, I mean I've developed an app and I'd like to add its icon to this screen (currently, the only way I know how to start the app is manually via `adb`):

[image]